# Changing Div content with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've read through many other questions on this but none seem to solve my problem.

I have created a div element which houses an icon from fontawesome. It's a media player icon where i use an if/else argument to change from PLAY to PAUSE and back again. Without using the fontawesome element it works but i like the icon. I've also looked up using jquery instead but it's a little beyond my knowledge.

It's the **i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"** it doesn't like.

```
<script language="javascript">
        function chPlay2() {
            
    if (document.getElementById("player").title =="Toggle Play") 
    {
        audio.play();
        document.getElementById("player").title = "Toggle Stop";
        document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i>";
    }
    else
    {
        audio.pause();
        document.getElementById("player").title = "Toggle Play";
        document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try `'&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>'` (single quotes)

Comment: you should escape the inner double quotes. Or wrap the string with single quotes like @B001ᛦ is suggesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use like this-

```
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = '&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
```

Just replace the double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's frustrating how long i was wracking my head around this to find it's such a simple solution!

Comment: It's my  pleasure @AYCE!

Comment: Due to some ajax elements i want to add i have to change the div from an ID to a class. I've changed to "document.getElementByClassName("player").innerHTML" and now it doesn't work. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: When you select by className it will return an array. So use like this- 
`document.getElementByClassName("player")[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You have a double qoute inside your string literals. Try using
the ***`*** for string template or escape your double qoutes using ***\*** (the escape character). it would look something like this

```
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = `&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i>`;
```

or alternatively,

```
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "&nbsp;<i class=\"fa fa-stop\" aria-hidden="true"></i>";
```

This is true for many languages so you might want to keep this in mind.